# About "write()" change string to byte

Tags: python, string, byte, encode

i want to use "ser.write()" ，but error say a is not byte.
so ,what can i do?

```
import serial
from time import sleep
import sys
ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyS0',9600,timeout=1);
try:
   whiel True:
            a = input()
            ser.write(a)
            sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
ser.close()
```

Comment: Does `ser.write(a.encode())` work?

Comment: i don't know. but now ,i use "ser.write(input().encode())",it can work.
and the new question is i want to input "10",but it only show "1"

Comment: I assume you use Phyton 2. In this case use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`.